# Force create Terms using tm package

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus

I have a corpus that has words such as 5k,50k,7.5k,75k,10K,100K. 
So when i create a TDM using the tm package, terms such as 10k and 100k are extracted separately. However , 5k and 7.5k are not extracted as separate terms. 
Now , i understand that after punctuation correction "7.5k" might be falling under "75k" terms , but whats going on with "5k" . Why is it not extracted as a term ?

Basically , i would want to know if there is way to FORCE tm package to look for specific words and extract them as key terms.

Any pointers would help !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you breaking words at punctuation? That is, is '.' a word-break character? If so, then the split of '7.5k' is ('7', '5k'), the second of which matches '5k'.

Comment: Thanks JWLM,  are you suggesting that i break the char at a decimal into 2 parts that tm can capture ?